# How to insert external javascript into a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to insert a custom JavaScript (a sketcher) into a Vue component but no luck so far. When I try inserting javascript directly into a template like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="sketcher">
        var sketcher = new ChemDoodle.SketcherCanvas('sketcher', 400, 300);
    </div>
</template>
```

I get an error: "Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed."
My another attempt is to create a component in a different .js file and import it into a Vue component.

sketcher.js:

```
export default ({
  mounted(){    
   return new ChemDoodle.SketcherCanvas('sketcher', 400, 300)
  }
})
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="sketcher">
       <app-sketcher></app-sketcher>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import sketcher from './sketcher';    
export default {
    components: {
    "app-sketcher": sketcher
    }
}
</script>
```

but I get this error: "Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined". I would highly appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this or to propose other options of embedding javascript into a Vue component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error message is self-explanatory: you cannot put a `<script>` tag in the `<template>` of a single-file Vue component.

In your second example, you aren't defining a template for the `app-sketcher` component when you register it in your `Home.vue` file. Your `sketcher.js` file exports just the definition for a `mounted` hook and nothing else.

---

You can make a `Sketcher.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div id="sketcher"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {    
    return new ChemDoodle.SketcherCanvas('sketcher', 400, 300)
  }
}
</script>
```

And then use import it and use it in your `Home.vue` file like so:

```
<template>
  <app-sketcher/>
</template>

<script>
import AppSketcher from './Sketcher';    
export default {
  components: { AppSketcher }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I get this error after implementing your suggestions: [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: c is undefined"  found in ---> <AppSketcher> at src/components/Sketcher.vue <Home> at src/components/Home.vue
         <VApp>
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that error. Does your `Sketcher.vue` file look exactly like my example? If not, you probably have a syntax error somewhere in that file's `mounted` hook

Comment: I found my mistake and besides a missing '.vue' in import line, your code is working great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The sketcher is displayed on the page but unfortunately it is mounted to the bottom of the page. After inspection I found that the sketcher was inserted below <script src="./dist/build.js"></script>. Any ideas why this can happen?